# bash kill process if it takes too long to shutdown

Tags: linux, bash, centos, rhel, supervisord

I have a group of supervisord run process that I want to automate starting and stopping with a script.
But sometimes the supervisor shutdown command takes too long to complete and wait times start to pile up.
Currently I am doing:

```
     for each in "${args[@]}"; do
             (supervisorctl -c configs/supervisord_${each}.conf shutdown) & sleep 8s & (kill -9 `ps aux | grep supervisor| grep ${each} | a    wk '{print $2}'` && kill -9 `ps aux | grep supervisor| grep ${each} | awk '{print $2}'`)
         done
```

Is there a cleaner way I can kill the supervisor process, after a few seconds, if it takes too long to stop?
To be clear, I am trying to kill the supervisor process that I am trying to shutdown with `supervisorctl -c {config path} shutdown`, and not the `supervisorctl shutdown` command itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, if you have a look at `bash(1)` (or `sh(1)` in case you use plain bourne shell) you will see that there's a variable `$!` that stores the pid of the last background executed command (`&`), so you can substitute the body of the loop with:

```
supervisorctl -c configs/supervisrod_${each}.conf shutdown &
pid_to_kill=$!
(sleep 8; kill -9 "${pid_to_kill}") &
```

searching the process table is an expensive operation that you should avoid.  Remember also that a `kill -9` doesn't allow the program to close cleanly, and you can probably miss some data.

## SECOND TRY

If you want to kill the supervisor (and not the `supervisorctl` you use to control it) you can simply check if it writes some pid file in `/var/run` directory.  As it is common use, if you need an unrelated process (like `supervisorctl`, with no parental father-to-child relationship) to get access to its pid and be able to send signals to it.

Comment: Hi Luis sorry for the confusion, I am trying to kill the running supervisor process, that a supervisor shutdown is taking too long to complete, not the `supervisorctl -c {conf name} shutdown` process itself. I want to abandon trying to shut it down and just kill it instead.

Comment: Does the supervisor write (a common use) its pid in `/var/run` directory?  If it does, probably is better to dig there, as gathering the info from the `ps(1)` output takes a lot of resources.  If the supervisor is a program written by you, could be a good idea to make it write it's pid somewhere, and then... what's the use of the supervisorctl program?  (If it cannot do its work correctly)  I think you need more thinking on that.

Comment: Yes pids are written into a `~/tmp/pids/{app}` for each process. Thanks!

Comment: ;)  Now I have to add my comments to the response... or I'll get downvoted :)

Comment: Sorry about that :-)